# Slick2D Methods are missing

Tags: java, slick2d, method-missing

I am using Slick2D to code a little game, and after a lot of time that already went into it, I changed my mind and decided that I indeed want the game to be resizable. So I tried to use the app.setResizable() command, as suggested on the Slick2D wiki (and here: [How to make slick2d resizable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052902/how-to-make-slick2d-resizable)). But my eclipse just didnt find that method, so I looked it up on the Internet again, and noticed that all attributes and methods reliative to resizing are missing (such as wasResized(), isResized(), setResizable(), etc..). I have the latest version of Slick2D and eclipse, and probably the answer is pretty obvious, but I have been looking for hours and just cant find it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What build version of slick are you using?

Comment: Build 237, the latest version (at least the latest on their website).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your StateBasedGame, in your main method, you can call lwjgl's Display object,

```
 Display.setResizable(true);
```

This will allow you to resize/maximize the Display window. Make sure you have a recent version of lwjgl!

If you would like to resize the window and make sure the graphics object refreshes it size, you should call this in your update method:

```
    if(Display.getWidth() != container.getWidth() || Display.getHeight() != container.getHeight()) {
        try {
            app.setDisplayMode(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight(), false);
            app.reinit();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And app is your AppGameContainer class. If you are doing gamestates, you can send a reference to the state when it is initialized. If not, you can make a global reference to your container so you can use this snippet of code anywhere in the class.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, but I already know that. My problem is that I want it to be resizable when you hover over the window border (I don't know how to describe it, I hope you know what I mean) so that the user can change the size like he wants.

Comment: check the edited answer ;) Also, I suggest looking into the Display object of the LWJGL library. There are a lot of useful methods there for the window itself.