# appgc.setResizable(true); error

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

So I've been making a game for a while now. Recently I ecnountered an error saying

```
 "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method setResizable(boolean) is undefined for the type AppGameContainer

at felix.riskminer.game.MainGame.main(MainGame.java:1760)"
```

This started happening as soon as I added `appgc.setResizable(true);` to the code.

The problem is that if I remove it I get a bunch of other errors. Any fix?

With `appgc.setResizable(true);`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method setResizable(boolean) is undefined for the type AppGameContainer

at felix.riskminer.game.MainGame.main(MainGame.java:1760)
```

without `appgc.setResizable(true);`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl64 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:72)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:87)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:117)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer$1.run(AppGameContainer.java:39)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.<clinit>(AppGameContainer.java:36)
    at felix.riskminer.game.MainGame.main(MainGame.java:1759)
```

LIBRARIES THAT ARE BEING USED: Slick2D and LWJGL

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For missing `setResiable` method: I can't find this method in the official documentation. It may depends on the version of slick you're using. To correct this you can go for this solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153057/slick2d-methods-are-missing)

> In your StateBasedGame, in your main method, you can call lwjgl's Display object,
>
> Display.setResizable(true);
>
> This will allow you to resize/maximize the Display window. Make sure
>   you have a recent version of lwjgl!

Check lwjgl jar and native, restart your IDE and come back if you still have problem with classloading.